# How to add or link purchased product to customer

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am doing migration from very old custom made ecommerce site that is working as subscription model. I have 3 different products that contains custom data to is available to customers that have purchased to product.

So i am importing customers by their email address and i need to add products to their purchase / order history so the can get their hands on into custom data.

So how to link a product  to customer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not so sure about those custom fields but it seem like what to need is to create orders programmatically, where you "link" existing users and existing products.

Luckily, WooCommerce allow us to do that :)

take a look at this code:

```
function create_order() {
     // Create product
     $product = WC_Helper_Product::create_simple_product();
     WC_Helper_Shipping::create_simple_flat_rate();
     $order_data = array('status' => 'pending', 'customer_id' => 1, 'customer_note' => '', 'total' => '');
     $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = '127.0.0.1';

     // Required, else wc_create_order throws an exception
     $order = wc_create_order($order_data);

     // Add order products
     $item_id = $order->add_product($product, 4);

     // Set billing address
     $billing_address = array('country' => 'US', 'first_name' => 'Jeroen', 'last_name' => 'Sormani', 'company' => 'WooCompany', 'address_1' => 'WooAddress', 'address_2' => '', 'postcode' => '123456', 'city' => 'WooCity', 'state' => 'NY', 'email' => 'admin@example.org', 'phone' => '555-32123');
     $order->set_address($billing_address, 'billing');

     // Add shipping costs
     $shipping_taxes = WC_Tax::calc_shipping_tax('10', WC_Tax::get_shipping_tax_rates());
     $order->add_shipping(new WC_Shipping_Rate('flat_rate_shipping', 'Flat rate shipping', '10', $shipping_taxes, 'flat_rate'));

     // Set payment gateway
     $payment_gateways = WC()->payment_gateways->payment_gateways();
     $order->set_payment_method($payment_gateways['bacs']);

     // Set totals
     $order->set_total(10, 'shipping');
     $order->set_total(0, 'cart_discount');
     $order->set_total(0, 'cart_discount_tax');
     $order->set_total(0, 'tax');
     $order->set_total(0, 'shipping_tax');
     $order->set_total(40, 'total');
     // 4 x $10 simple helper product

     return wc_get_order($order->id);
 }
```

at the 5th line, you set the customer ID
and, at the 12th line, you assign the product to the order.

caveat: I'm not sure how much of this snippet is required by wc_create_order(), as the official documentation is very poor.

I'd try to run this function as clean as possible, just using the minimum information (or the information that you have available).

Something like this:

```
function create_order() {
     // Create product
     $product = WC_Helper_Product::create_simple_product();

     $order_data = array('status' => 'pending', 'customer_id' => 1, 'customer_note' => '', 'total' => '');

     // Required, else wc_create_order throws an exception
     $order = wc_create_order($order_data);

     // Add order products
     $item_id = $order->add_product($product, 4);


     // Set totals
     //$order->set_total(40, 'total');

     return wc_get_order($order->id);
 }
```

good luck!